# Upgrading Beagle Bone Black using an external microSD card (together with SSH)

Tags: linux, embedded, debian, beagleboneblack

I am trying to upgrade BBB to the latest version of Linux (on the microSD that is built in into the board). Here are my steps:

1. Apply the image to an external microSD card
2. Boot BBB using the external microSD card.
3. Download the same image again (external microSD). I got it from http://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-7.8-lxde-4gb-armhf-2015-03-01-4gb.img.xz.
4. Then, I used `dd if=imagefile.img of=/dev/mmcblk1`.
5. After 15 minutes, I got the error: No space left on the device.

Do you know how this can be resolved? When I tried to use `dd` but instead of the image file, I had the entire microSD card (external), it worked. The thing is, the external microSD card had the same image.

**Edit**:

Note: When I had the if parameter set to the external SD card, I did not have the last, third partition. It's only there to allow me store the image (of it self).

```
 External microSD

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048      198655       98304    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          198656     7577599     3689472   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3         7577600    22257663     7340032   83  Linux

internal microSD

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk1p1   *        2048      198655       98304    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2          198656     7577599     3689472   83  Linux
```

From lsblk:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk0      179:0    0  14.9G  0 disk
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    96M  0 part /media/BEAGLEBONE_
|-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   3.5G  0 part /
`-mmcblk0p3  179:3    0     7G  0 part /media/7ea42485-bebc-451d-bb10-    d0349cb4c582
 mmcblk1      179:8    0   3.6G  0 disk
|-mmcblk1p1  179:9    0    96M  0 part /media/BEAGLEBONE
`-mmcblk1p2  179:10   0   3.5G  0 part
```

From `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mmcblk1` I get `3867148288`. This is supposed to be the no. of bytes, so ~3.86714829 GB

Comment: your image is too big for the device.

Comment: @MattJoyce, It's strange though since it worked when I used the entire microSD card as the "if" parameter (because microSD is basically the same image that I got when I used Win32DiskImager).

Comment: how much space is on the MicroSD... df -h  or dmesg or fdisk

Comment: @Matt Joyce, I've added results from fdisk -l.

Comment: Can power supply be an issue? When I did it last time, it was plugged directly into a USB adapter, but now, I had the BBB connected to USB 2 in a laptop.

Comment: From what I am seeing you are trying to fit a 4GB image on a 2GB microSD card.  That's obviously a very unlikely scenario.

Comment: @Matt Joyce, It should be 3.8 GB according to blockdev,

Comment: I may have done the math wrong in my head.  Still less than 4GB

Comment: It's strange though, BBB official website tells me to use this image. That's strange.

Comment: The image file seems to be 3.6 GB, which should be enough.

Comment: A file size of "3.6GB" could mean anything between 3.55GB and 3.65GB and assuming GB = 1024^3 bytes it will either fit or not depending on the exact value. What's the output of `wc -c imagefile.img`?

Comment: @maxy, since I'm on a Windows machine right now, I looked at the file details page, which gave me the value "3,879,731,200 bytes"

Comment: So you're short by 12MB. Next question: how important are those last 12MB actually ;-)